# jQuery Copy dynamically added table row values into next row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Location</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Valid</td>
        <td>Add</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_clone">
        <td>
            <input type="text" >
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" >
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="datepicker">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" >
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" name="add" value="Add">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to insert only the values from the table row (not include the input filed) into next row in the table.

Please give your valuable suggestions.

Comment: you mean in button click you need to create a new row with the added values?What you mean by valid check box?

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3rgzzt95/. use this as a reference and add validations and all accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'll give you something for your information

```js
var localDb = [];
var emptyVar = '';

(function(){

 //define local storage
 var dataFiles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
 console.log(dataFiles);
 if (dataFiles == null){
  $('#no-data').show();
  //alert('its working');
 }else{
  $('#no-data').hide();
  $('.data-box').html('<table><tbody><tr><th>Serial No</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Email</th><th>Address</th><th>Options</th></tr></tbody><tbody id="uploadFiles"></tbody></table>');
  for (var i=0; i<dataFiles.length; i++){
   localDb.push(dataFiles[i]);
   emptyVar += '<tr id="number'+i+'">';
   emptyVar += '<td>'+i+'</td>';
   emptyVar += '<td>'+dataFiles[i].name+'</td>';
   emptyVar += '<td>'+dataFiles[i].age+'</td>';
   emptyVar += '<td>'+dataFiles[i].email+'</td>';
   emptyVar += '<td>'+dataFiles[i].address+'</td>';
   emptyVar += '<td>'+'<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="getId(this);" />'+'</td>';
   emptyVar += '</tr>'
  };

  $('#uploadFiles').html(emptyVar);
 };
})();

function add(){
 var name = $('#name').val();
 var age = $('#age').val();
 var email = $('#email').val();
 var address = $('#address').val();

 var fullDetails = {};
 fullDetails.name = name;
 fullDetails.age = age;
 fullDetails.email = email;
 fullDetails.address = address;

 localDb.push(fullDetails);
 window.localStorage.setItem('key',JSON.stringify(localDb));
 window.location.reload();
};

function getId(e){
 var removeID = e.closest('tr').id;
 //alert(removeID);
 var dataFiles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
 localDb.pop(dataFiles[removeID]);
 $('#'+removeID).remove();
 window.localStorage.setItem('key',JSON.stringify(localDb));
 window.location.reload();

};
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.outer-wrapper {
 float:left;
 width:100%;
}
.form-area {
 width:100%;
 float:left;
 height:100%;
 background:#CCC;
 padding:15px;
}
.data-box {
 width:100%;
 float:left;
 height:100%;
 margin-top: 6px;
}
input[type='text']{
 width:20%;
 float:left;
 padding:10px 15px;
 margin-bottom:15px;
 margin-right: 15px;
}
input[type='button']{
 width:15%;
 float:left;
 margin-top: 1px;
 padding:8px 15px;
 margin-bottom:15px;
 background:#F00;
 border:none;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:15px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 cursor:pointer;
}

#no-data {
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-top: 15%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
table,tbody {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
}

tr {
 width:100%;
 float:left;
}
th {
 font-size:18px;
 color:#000;
 font-weight:bold;
   
}

td , th{
 width:18.3%;
 float:left;
 text-align:center;
 border:1px solid #000;
 padding: 15px;
}
td {
 min-height:55px;
}
td input[type="button"] {
 padding: 7px 15px;
 font-size: 12px;
 margin: 9px 0;
 width: 100%;
}
td:last-child {
 padding: 0 15px;
}
.form-area h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
td:first-child ,th:first-child {
 width: 8%;
} 
td:nth-child(2), th:nth-child(2) {
    width: 8%;
}
td:nth-child(3), th:nth-child(3) {
    width: 7%;
}
td:nth-child(5), th:nth-child(5) {
    width: 50%;
}
td:last-child ,th:last-child {
 width: 8%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
 <div class="form-area">
     <h2>Fill your data</h2>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Age" id="age" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Address" id="address" />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" id="sumbit" onclick="add();" />
    </div><!-- /.form-area -->
    <div class="data-box">
        <h2 id="no-data">No data found here </h2>
    </div><!-- /.data-box -->
</div><!-- /.outer-wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var new_row = '<tr>';
$('table .tr_clone td').each(function(){
    new_row += '<td>'+$(this).find('input').val()+'</td>';
});
new_row += '</tr>';
$('table').append(new_row);
```

Comment: this answer fails when input type is "html select"

Answer (score 0):

```
<--HTML--->  
  <table id="mytable">
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Location</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Valid</td>
        <td>Add</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr_clone">
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="tname">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="tloc">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="tdate">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="datepicker">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" name="add" value="Add" id="addbtn">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

/**JQUERY**/

    $("#addbtn").click(function(){

    var name = $("#tname").val();
    var loc = $("#tloc").val();
    var date = $("#tdate").val();

        $('#mytable tr:last').after('<tr><td>'+name+'</td><td>'+loc+'</td><td>'+date+'</td></tr>');
    });
```

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/4387657/santhucool tds are dynamically added, i can't predict it

Comment: @you mean it will be any number? does all `td` contain input boxes? or anything else just like checkbox as you mentined in your example?

Comment: yes..any number,as per user select. td can contains input boxes, select controls, check boxes etc

Comment: user select? what you mean by that? The table td logic you have to generate dynamically? What you mean I did not get it.