# Convert input fields to array and save to Local Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, local-storage

I have several input fields that I need to convert to an array in order to save them to Local Storage.

A Small script (jQuery) goes and scans all the input fields, and sets their names determined by the input field ID.

**HTML:**

```
<input class="field" type="checkbox" id="field-01"> I have done it!
<input class="field" type="text" id="field-02"> Comment on how it went?
```

**JS:**

```
function dataSave(){
   $(".field").each(function(formField){
      var formFieldLoad = $(this).val(localStorage.field);
      formField = $(formField).val(this);
   });
}
```

So basically I would need to drive in the data and values inside the input fields (checkboxes, radio buttons, sliders (value attribute driven) and text fields) to the Local Storage in an array, in order to save everything and not just the last field. How can I achieve this?

Also, checkboxes need to be inspected if they're checked or not, while text fields need to have their content saved. Will this cause an issue on the saving progress?

**UPDATE:** I have tried to convert all fields to array, but I don't know how to use that array further to pass it on to the Local Storage. I've looked all over the internet and I'm starting to think there are so many ways to do this, but yet I can not figure out what is the suitable solution for my case.

Comment: That depends on the data stored on localstorage. can you add that up in the question with dummy data if that is sensitive?

Comment: The application is merely a to-do list, so nothing too sensitive included. I also have sliders (jquery-ui) that need to be counted in, but they work around their value attribute, so shouldn't be a problem. This Local Storage integration is just temporary, to help me develop the application further before integrating it with a bigger system that then receives the saved data to MySQL database, so in that point Local Storage will be thrown away, at least from the production version.

Comment: check this link what i did. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38322394/jquery-copy-dynamically-added-table-row-values-into-next-row/38328193#38328193

Comment: check this link. > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38322394/jquery-copy-dynamically-added-table-row-values-into-next-row/38328193#38328193

Comment: @TommyRiordan That answer has absolutely nothing to do with Local Storage, or my case in any way.

Comment: All you need is this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage after you get your values into an array ..

Comment: The problem is (as described) that I can't figure out how to do it. I know how to read those documentaries, but I don't know how to implement the two things together, that's why I'm asking a question over here. If I were to seek some reference to a document, I would be using Google instead. Could you provide me an example on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you need to add all values and IDs in JSON object using `.each` then to use `JSON.stringify()` together with `localStorage.setItem()` to put them in local storage:

```
<input class="field" type="checkbox" id="field-01"> I have done it!
<input class="field" type="text" id="field-02"> Comment on how it went?
<input type="button" value="Save to LS" onclick="dataSave()">
<script>
    function dataSave(){
        var fields = {};
        $('.field').each(function(){
            fields[this.id] = this.value;
        })
        localStorage.setItem('fieldString',JSON.stringify(fields));

        console.log(localStorage.getItem('fieldString'));               // Output: {"field-01":"on","field-02":"1234"}
        console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fieldString')));   //Output: Object {field-01: "on", field-02: "1234"}
    }
</script>
```

If you need that object in future, you can easily get the string with `localStorage.getItem('fieldString')`

Comment: Thank you, your explanation was clear and so was the example itself! Got it to work like a charm. :) Any ideas/tips on how to parse the array so that I only get the field ID:s (names), not the values?

Comment: You are welcome. In `fields` array (and `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fieldString')` if you fetch it from local storage) you have both properties - names (IDs) and values, so walking trough the array you can parse them easily by using again jquery `$.each` - see here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: Thanks again, I've managed to parse the results! Now is the time to fill up the form back up again as it was saved (when the page is reloaded), but that might be the point of a new question entirely.

Answer (score 1):

To persist data, use [`localStorage.setItem(key, value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem). It will then be available for later retrieval with [`localStore.getItem(key)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem).

An important point to note is that the localStorage stores textual data. If you want to persist Objects, you'll have to encode them before you persist them and decode them after you've retrieved them :

```
> test={a:1, b:2}
< Object {a: 1, b: 2}
> localStorage.setItem("test", test)
< undefined
> localStorage.getItem("test")
< "[object Object]"                                     // that's not very interesting
> localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(test))
< undefined
> JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test")) 
< Object {a: 1, b: 2}                                   //that's better
```

Another point of importance is that `localStorage.setItem` can throw exceptions. For example, `Opera` will always throw an exception if it is in private browsin mode. You will want to catch these.

For your specific problem, I suggest you store the fields as properties of an Object, that you'll store in localStorage :

```
function dataSave(){
   var formData = {};
   $(".field").each(function(formField){
      formData[this.id] = this.value;
   });
   try {
       localStorage.setItem("formData", JSON.stringify(formData));
   } catch (err) {
       console.log("Couldn't persist formData : " + err);
   }
}
```