# get val() from dynamically generated text element

Tags: jquery, html

Okay, so I have some dynamically generated text boxes whose values aren't found when I call .val(). The text input that was rendered on page load will return a value with .val(), but all the rest will not.

If this example isn't sufficient to get an answer then I will edit the question with my actual code, but I've done my best to accurately simplify it.

JQuery:

```
numBoxes = 0

function newText(){
  numBoxes++
  $('<div id="' + numBoxes + '"><input id="soft_text_' + numBoxes + 
    '" type="text"></div>').insertBefore($('button#new'))
}

function logHard(){
  console.log($('input#hard_text').val())
}

function logSoft(){
  $('div').each(function(){
    console.log($('input#soft_text_' + this.id).val())
  })
}
```

HTML:

```
<html><body>
<input id="hard_text" type="text" name="first_text">
<button id="new" onclick="newText()">Add new text box</button>
<button onclick="logHard()">Log first text box</button>
<button onclick="logSoft()">Log new text boxes</button>
</body></html>
```

Comment: It might be because there isn't any text in them?

Comment: *"I've done my best to accurately simplify it."* Simplifying is good, but it should be a [mcve]. In this case, since it's browser-based tech, make it a **runnable** MCVE using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button).

Comment: May be this is what you need [Please check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38322394/jquery-copy-dynamically-added-table-row-values-into-next-row/38328193#38328193)

Comment: Did you actually try your code?  It works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/kfssqg0c/ (so doesn't represent your actual code if your actual code doesn't work)

Comment: "..dynamically generated text boxes..."  "..that was rendered on load will return.. rest will not.." sounds like a common problem with binding events to elements that don't exist yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @freedomn-m It does, but the only events in this code are bound to buttons that do exist.

Comment: It doesn't work on your jfiddle link. It doesn't matter that they don't exist, because they won't be called if they don't exist. I solved the problem, just needed a better selector. As for a runnable MCVE, I'll look into that next time, new to SO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should improve your selectors. Keeping an incrementing ID is usually a sign you're doing something wrong.

For instance...

```
function newText(){
  $('<div class="addedbox"><input type="text"></div>').insertBefore($('button#new'));
}
function logHard(){
  console.log($('input#hard_text').val());
}
function logSoft(){
  $('div.addedbox>input').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
  })
}
```

Comment: Who's to say this solves OPs problem? This could have been a (long) comment.

Comment: While I agree that the IDs a somewhat dodgy, it's unlikely this would sove whatever the actual issue is.

Comment: Thank you for tipping me off to '>'.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem. @Niet, it was your suggestion to use better selectors that helped. I'll work towards using selectors that don't require sequential identifying in the future, but this will make it work today.

```
function logSoft(){
  $('div').each(function(){
    console.log($('div#' + this.id + ' > input').val())
  })
}
```