# Cant seem to add a dynamically rows in html table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table which needs to have a dynamic rows to be added. Ive set a limit of 4 rows which will change depending on the use of the table.

I am so confused to why my add row isnt working. Im sure its probably something very simple but im in real need of this being solved. Please advise on solution

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>

 <!--<script src="addrow.js" language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js">   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js">   </script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <script>
 $(function() {
$('.date-picker').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear,      inst.selectedMonth, 1));
    }
});
 });
 </script>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 var counter = 1;
 var limit = 4;
 jQuery('a.addrow').click(function(event){
     if (counter == limit)  {
      alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
 }else{
event.preventDefault();
counter++;
var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" name="' +
    counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="' +
    counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="' +
    counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="' +
    counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="' +
    counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="' +
    counter + '"/></td></tr>');
  jQuery('table.history').append(newRow);
  }});
   </script>

 </head>

 <html>
 <body>

 <style>
 .ui-datepicker-calendar {
  display: none;
  }
  </style>

 <table width="100%">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="4" width="100%">
 <h1>title</h1>
 <p>some content</p>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="history" width="100%">

<tr><td>Dates(Months &amp; Year)</td></tr>

 <tr><td>From</td><td>To</td><td colspan="2">NAME - Company/ College/ Job     Centre/ Armed Services</p>
</td><td colspan="2">Address</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
</td>
<td>
    <input name="toDate" id="toDate" class="date-picker" />
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" />
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" />
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" />
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" />
</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
  <a href="" title="" class="addrow">Add row</a>
```

Comment: Why are you using multiple versions of `jquery.js`? i.e. `jquery-1.7.js`/`1.4.1/jquery.js`  And __your code works__

Comment: This seems to work fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/m49g53eq/ Can you produce a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem you're having (or, at very least define "not working")

Comment: I replicated it on fiddle, its working. Just i added only one `jQuery` [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jo_Geek/bxcmw8j9/)

Comment: Its working fine [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/1L2ocx4f/#&togetherjs=UKd7Vwc8ef). Update your jquery version.

Comment: Im currently running off a local host does this have an impact?

Comment: @user3473873 no, it doesnt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Copy dynamically added table row values into next row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38322394/jquery-copy-dynamically-added-table-row-values-into-next-row)

Comment: @user3473873 i have fixed your code and added answer. please let me know for any issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has lot of issues. Please find below working example.

1. You did not have `tbody` defined in your table.
2. `a` tag changed to normal `button` type.
3. jquery multiple versions included

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
  $('.date-picker').datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      showButtonPanel: true,
      dateFormat: 'MM yy',
      onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
      }
    });
  
   jQuery('button.addrow').click(function(event) {
    if (counter == limit) {
      alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
    } else {
      event.preventDefault();
      counter++;
      var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" name="' +
        counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="' +
        counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="' +
        counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="' +
        counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="' +
        counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="' +
        counter + '"/></td></tr>');
      jQuery('table.history').append(newRow);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!--<script src="addrow.js" language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script>
  
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var counter = 1;
  var limit = 4;
 
</script>


  <table class="history" width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Dates(Months &amp; Year)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>From</td>
      <td>To</td>
      <td colspan="2"><p>NAME - Company/ College/ Job Centre/ Armed Services</p>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">Address</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="toDate" id="toDate" class="date-picker" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" />
      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
  </table>
  <button class="addrow">Add row</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by just including 1 version of jQuery - not the answer to your question, but wont hurt.

---

Then, to get your code to work, your event handler must be inside of a document ready function.

```
$(function() {
  $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear,      inst.selectedMonth, 1));
    }
  });

  //   put your addrow code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two things here:

Firstly, you probably need a document ready wrapper (i.e. `jQuery(function() {... your code here ...});` ) around your addRow click event, meaning that is running before there is a `.addrow` element to bind to.

Secondly, you aren't using `event.preventDefault()` within that click binding. That means that the link is being followed and as it doesn't have a location, but does have a href, it's loading the page again.

Once you add those bits, the code works for me - here's a JS Bin link showing it working: https://jsbin.com/kiwako/edit?html,js,console,output

I didn't include some of your datePicker JS for simplicity's sake.

Answer (score -3):

Try to append the row to your table tag
like ("your table selector").append("tr html here") in js file;