# How to fix my login issue with local storage?

Tags: javascript, php, html, local-storage

Basically I have 2 files... register.html and login.js.... I am able to store user's registration details into local storage and then parsed it as objects in array.... I need to log in properly(when user and pass match, alert box indicates login successful and then PHP file will redirect user, and if no match, alert box will indicate for that separately) and then second alert box as you have successfully signed in and then it will not redirect me as the PHP file is meant to do so when the user and pass match local storage... Any clues??

Comment: can you check with this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/38328193/6572922

Comment: Sorry i'm not on that level where i can distinguish differences and compare to mine to make differences with my code... i just need support in altering my code to allow it to login properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just not iterating correctly through credentials, you have to wait until you are sure that the current login credentials are not equal to any of the stored credentials, so you have to get this part of code out of the for loop:

```
alert('Invalid Username or Password! Please try again.');
event.preventDefault();
window.location="Login.html";
```

try this code for validating the login:

```
function validlogin(event) {
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
var entriesJSON = localStorage.getItem('allEntries');
if (!entriesJSON) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Nothing stored!");
    return;
}
var allEntries = JSON.parse(entriesJSON);
var isCorrectCredentials=false;
for (var i = 0; i < allEntries.length; i++) {
    var entry = allEntries[i];
    var storedUserName = entry.user;
    var storedPassWord = entry.pass;

    var storedEmailAddress = entry.email;
    if (username == storedUserName && password == storedPassWord) {
        isCorrectCredentials=true;
        alert("Successfully logged in!");
        return;
    } }
   if(!isCorrectCredentials){
        alert('Invalid Username or Password! Please try again.');
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location="Login.html";     
    }
}
```

this way you will login if the current username and password are correct and notify the rest of the code using:

```
isCorrectCredentials=true;
```

that the login info was true and you are successfully logged in.
and the part of code that should be executed if the login info is not true will be executed 1 time max.

Comment: Wow it worked, can you explain briefly what you had to doto make that work, and btw.... Shokran :)

Comment: I will edit the answer to explain what was wrong! , 3afwan ;)

Comment: Thanks habibi, really really appreciate it