# Adding values of each cell in a row of a table

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I've a table where I use to enter daily stock reports, each table cell is an input file of type number. I want to perform some calculation on each row in the table. Whenever an input field value is change I've to perform calculation of each row. Please see the image below for better understanding:

[image]

```js
$('#stock_report input').on('keyup', function() {
  var bbo_bags = parseFloat($('#bbo_bags').val());
  var bbo_mt = parseFloat($('#bbo_mt').val());
  var bbr_bags = parseFloat($('#bbr_bags').val());
  var bbr_mt = parseFloat($('#bbr_mt').val());
  var bbi_bags = parseFloat($('#bbi_bags').val());
  var bbi_mt = parseFloat($('#bbi_mt').val());

  var bbc_bags = bbo_bags - bbr_bags + bbi_bags;
  var bbc_mt = bbo_mt - bbr_mt + bbi_mt;

  alert(bbc_bags);

  $('#bbc_bags').val(bbc_bags);
  $('#bbc_mt').val(bbc_mt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="stock-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S.No.</th>
      <th>Name of the Material</th>
      <th colspan="2">Opening Stock</th>
      <th colspan="2">Receipts</th>
      <th colspan="2">Issues</th>
      <th colspan="2">Closing Stock</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="stock_report">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Bags</td>
      <td>MT</td>
      <td>Bags</td>
      <td>MT</td>
      <td>Bags</td>
      <td>MT</td>
      <td>Bags</td>
      <td>MT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Boiled Bran</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" step="0.001" name="bbo_bags" id="bbo_bags">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" step="0.001" name="bbo_mt" id="bbo_mt">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" step="0.001" name="bbr_bags" id="bbr_bags">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" step="0.001" name="bbr_mt" id="bbr_mt">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" step="0.001" name="bbi_bags" id="bbi_bags">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" step="0.001" name="bbi_mt" id="bbi_mt">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" step="0.001" name="bbc_bags" id="bbc_bags">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" step="0.001" name="bbc_mt" id="bbc_mt">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: 1. Dont just add image to OP  2. Include all relevant code to OP

Comment: @guradio Actually I don't have any idea on how to solve them, so I just posted an image of my requirement

Comment: SO is not a write me my code site mate.. you have to do it yourself then as for help if you get stuck into some problem

Comment: @guradio I've updated my post

Comment: take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/38328193/6572922

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#stock_report").delegate('#bbo_bags', 'change', function (event) {
 var bbo_bags = parseFloat($('#bbo_bags').val());
  $("#stock_report #bbc_bags").val(bbo_bags);
});

$("#stock_report").delegate('#bbr_bags', 'change', function (event) {
 var bbo_bags = parseFloat($('#bbo_bags').val());
 var bbr_bags = parseFloat($('#bbr_bags').val());
 var tot=bbo_bags - bbr_bags ;

 $("#stock_report #bbc_bags").val(tot);
});

$("#stock_report").delegate('#bbi_bags', 'change', function (event) {
 var bbo_bags = parseFloat($('#bbo_bags').val());
 var bbr_bags = parseFloat($('#bbr_bags').val());
 var bbi_bags = parseFloat($('#bbi_bags').val());
 var tot=bbo_bags - bbr_bags + bbi_bags;

 $("#stock_report #bbc_bags").val(tot);
});


$("#stock_report").delegate('#bbo_mt', 'change', function (event) {
 var bbo_mt = parseFloat($('#bbo_mt').val());
  $("#stock_report #bbc_mt").val(bbo_mt);
});

$("#stock_report").delegate('#bbr_mt', 'change', function (event) {
 var bbo_mt = parseFloat($('#bbo_mt').val());
 var bbr_mt = parseFloat($('#bbr_mt').val());
 var tot=bbo_mt - bbr_mt ;

 $("#stock_report #bbc_mt").val(tot);
});

$("#stock_report").delegate('#bbi_mt', 'change', function (event) {
 var bbo_mt = parseFloat($('#bbo_mt').val());
 var bbr_mt = parseFloat($('#bbr_mt').val());
 var bbi_mt = parseFloat($('#bbi_mt').val());
 var tot=bbo_mt - bbr_mt + bbi_mt;

 $("#stock_report #bbc_mt").val(tot);
});
```

update your script for calculation. I hope this code will solve problem little more.